Applying different styling to inputs which are dirty and valid and dirty invalid with sass
I am trying to achieve following styling:

Pristine, valid input have default styling
Dirty inputs have blue background, blue border, white text and white placeholder text
ALL invalid inputs have red border

It shall look like this:

I use Angluar which provides the ng-dirty, ng-valid and ng-invalid classes
So I created following SASS code:
@mixin dirty-marking {
  background-color: $blue !important;
  color: $white !important;

  &.ng-valid {
    border-color: $blue !important;
  }
}

input.ng-dirty,
input.ng-dirty::placeholder {
  @include dirty-marking;
}

input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid $red !important;
}

I use the dirty-marking mixin also to style some custom checkboxes, dropdowns ...
Using it like this the does not apply the blue border to the valid, dirty inputs. After checking the output of the SASS compiler it turned out, that this results in a CSS like this:
input.ng-dirty,
input.ng-dirty::placeholder {
    background-color: blue !important;
    color: white !important;
}

input.ng-dirty.ng-valid,
  input.ng-dirty::placeholder.ng-valid {
    border-color: blue !important;
}

The issue lies within input.ng-dirty::placeholder.ng-valid, after removing the trailing .ng-valid it started to work. Although I understand why it is like this I am unable to come up with proper solution
EDIT:
I was able to come up with a solution, which feels more like a workaround:
@mixin dirty-marking($with-border-color: true) {
  background-color: $blue !important;
  color: $white !important;

  @if $with-border-color {
    &.ng-valid {
      border-color: $blue !important;
    }
  }
}


input.ng-dirty {
  @include dirty-marking;
}

input.ng-dirty::placeholder {
  @include dirty-marking($with-border-color: false);
}

input.ng-invalid {
  border: 1px solid $red !important;
}

This way I can prohibit the creation of the problematic input.ng-dirty::placeholder.ng-valid selector. I wonder whether there is a more elegant solution or if I can have something like
@mixin dirty-marking {
  background-color: $blue !important;
  color: $white !important;

  @if "& is not ::placeholder" {
    &.ng-valid {
      border-color: $blue !important;
    }
  }
}


it would be easier to solve if you could provide some example html
